# MySQL Query Never Returns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

**EDIT:** This has been solved, requiring a subquery into the appearances table. Here is the working solution.

```
SELECT concat(m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLast) as Name, 
   m.playerID as playerID, 
   sum(b.HR) as HR
FROM Master AS m
INNER JOIN Batting AS b
  ON m.playerID=b.playerID
WHERE ((m.weight/(m.height*m.height))*703) >= 27.99
AND m.playerID in (SELECT playerID FROM appearances GROUP BY playerID HAVING SUM(G_1b+G_dh)/SUM(G_All) >= .667)
GROUP BY playerID, Name
HAVING HR >= 100
ORDER BY HR desc;
```

I'm working with the Lahman baseball stat database, if anyone's familiar.

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all large, slugging first basemen, and the data I need is spread across three different tables. The way I'm doing this is finding players of a minimum BMI, who have spent at least 2/3 of their time at first/designated hitter, and have a minimum number of home runs.

'Master' houses player names, height, weight (for BMIs).

'Batting' houses HR.

'Appearances' houses games played at first, games played at DH, and total games.

All three databases are connected by the same 'playerID' value.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT concat(m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLast) as Name, 
   m.playerID as playerID, 
   sum(b.HR) as HR
FROM Master AS m
INNER JOIN Batting AS b
  ON m.playerID=b.playerID
INNER JOIN Appearances AS a
  ON m.playerID=a.playerID
GROUP BY Name, playerID
HAVING ((m.weight/(m.height*m.height))*703) >= 27.99 
  AND ((SUM(IFNULL(a.G_1b,0)+IFNULL(a.G_dh,0)))/SUM(IFNULL(a.G_All,0))) >= .667
  AND HR >= 200
ORDER BY HR desc;
```

This appears correct to me, but when entered it never returns (runs forever) - for some reason I think it has something to do with the inner join of the appearances table. I also feel like there's a problem with combining m.weight/m.height in a "HAVING" clause, but with aggregates involved I can't use "WHERE." What should I do?

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:** After removing all conditionals, I'm still getting the same (endless) result. This is my simpler query:

```
SELECT concat(m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLast) as Name, 
   m.playerID as playerID, 
   sum(b.HR) as HR
FROM Master AS m
INNER JOIN Batting AS b
  ON m.playerID=b.playerID
INNER JOIN Appearances AS a
  ON m.playerID=a.playerID
GROUP BY playerID, Name
ORDER BY HR desc;
```

Comment: Try moving the search criteria which don't depend on the aggregate (the SUM / GROUP BY) from your HAVING clause to a WHERE clause. Also, try leaving off the HAVING clause as you debug this query. Also, you don't need to defend SUM() clause inputs with IFNULL(whatever,0). SUM knows what to do with nulls.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried the suggestions, and it's still acting like an endless loop (never terminating) with both the WHERE and HAVING clauses removed. **EDIT:** sorry, obviously formatting doesn't work as well here, i'm editing the original post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the problem with your query is that each player has appeared many times (appearances) and at bat many times.  Say a player has been at bat 1000 times in 100 games.  Then the join -- as you have written it -- will have 100,000 rows just for that player.

This is just a guess because you have provided no sample data to verify if this is the problem.

The solution is to pre-aggregate the `appearances` and `games` tables as subqueries (at the `playerId` level) and then join them back.

Comment: Tinkering with these suggestions gave me a correct output! Thanks for your help!